# Migrate SVN to Git with filtered history

Tags: git, svn, version-control, version-control-migration

I would like to migrate a project from SVN to Git and retain history.

But because there are some configuration files with production passwords and other sensitive data in the SVN repository, I would like to exclude those few files from the migrated history.

How would I go about doing this?

Comment: How many commits have you and how many do you need to remove?

Comment: We have about 10 000 commits and about 10 configuration files. I checked one of the configuration files and it has about 100 commits. Though I wouldn't want to remove the whole commit for these 100 commits. I only want to remove the part of the commit that relates to the configuration file.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/872565/remove-sensitive-files-and-their-commits-from-git-history

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest solution would be to [migrate your SVN repository to Git](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-and-Other-Systems-Migrating-to-Git) *on your local machine* and then [remove the files that contain the sensitive data](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/) *before* you push the migrated history to a remote repository.

For example:

```
# Migrate the SVN project into a local repo
git svn clone svn://server/svnroot \
    --authors-file=authors.txt \
    --no-metadata \
    -s your_project

cd your_project   

# Remove the 'passwd.txt' file from the history of the local repo
git filter-branch --force --index-filter \
    'git rm --cached --ignore-unmatch passwd.txt' \
    --prune-empty --tag-name-filter cat -- --all
```

As long as you don't push the local Git repository to a remote location, you can safely remove any file from the entire history using [`git filter-branch`](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch). After the files are removed, it's safe to publish the repo anywhere you want.

An alternative solution to `git filter-branch` is to use a tool called [BFG Repo-Cleaner](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/), which uses its own -supposedly [*faster*](https://rtyley.github.io/bfg-repo-cleaner/#speed)- implementation to remove a file from the history of a Git repository. With [10.000 commits](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32760905/migrate-svn-to-git-with-filtered-history/32761309#comment53361396_32760905) it might be worth considering, since the performance of `git filter-branch` is going to be at least *linear* to the number of commits to process.

Comment: New recommended alternative: git-filter-repo https://github.com/newren/git-filter-repo

Answer (score -2):

Basically you have two strategies

1. Clean up SVN first and then migrate to GIT
2. Migrate first and then clean up in GIT

**Clean up SVN first and then migrate to GIT**

According to SVN:

*"(...)your only recourse is to svnadmin dump your repository, then pipe the dumpfile through svndumpfilter (excluding the bad path) into an svnadmin load command(...)"*

http://subversion.apache.org/faq.html#removal

**Migrate first and then clean up in GIT**

Github has a good article on this

https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data/